# Possibly unhandled rejection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to call `PUT`-method using `json-data`. But when I click on my `toggle_save()` button  to modify the data I am getting `404 error` and unhandled rejection.

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-show="contact" id="contacts_edit()">
<div>
 <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="toggle_edit()"> Edit </button>
 <button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="toggle_save(cts.selectedcontact)"> Save </button>         
</div>

<b> Street:</b> 
    <p ng-hide="editMode">      
    {{cts.selectedcontact.location.street}} 
  </p>
<input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="cts.selectedcontact.location.street"><br/>
```

#### AngularJS:

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(contacts, id) {
  $scope.selectedcontact = [];

  $http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + contacts.editmode,
    data: {
      selectedcontact: contacts.selectedcontact
    }
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.cts.selectedcontact = data;
  })
}
```

Comment: well, you're not handling any error in the call to `$http({` so, yeah, unhandled rejection will ensue

Answer (score 0):

You can handle unhandled rejections in the catch block. Your API is failing because of some mistake in your API call. Make sure the contacts data and its properties are correct.

**HTML**:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="toggle_save(cts.selectedcontact)"> Save </button>
```

**JS** :

```
 $scope.toggle_save = function(contacts) {
    $scope.selectedcontact = [];
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + contacts.editmode,
        data: {
            selectedcontact: contacts.selectedcontact
        }
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $scope.cts.selectedcontact = data.data;
    }).catch(function(data) {
       //handle rejections here
    });
}
```

Comment: **cts** is the alias name of the  controller and I am assigning the value to the **selectedcontact** object @Vivz

Comment: But what is id that is present as function parameter? And you are mixing $scope and cts which is a bad practise. Either use $scope or controller as , not both.

Comment: What are using for your backend? Is the Put Url correct?

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using? contacts.editmode and contacts.selectedcontact contain correct values?

Comment: I am using Angular 1.6 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154851/discussion-between-kishore-and-vivz).

Answer (score 0):

404 Error is coming because the API is not able to reach the URL.
The easiest way to test this will be copying and pasting the URL in a browser.

The unhandled rejection can be solved by placing a .catch() after .then(). The rejection will be passed as a parameter to this. You can console or take the appropriate action.

```
 $scope.toggle_save = function(contacts) {
    $scope.selectedcontact = [];
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + contacts.editmode,
            data: {
                selectedcontact: contacts.selectedcontact
            }
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $scope.cts.selectedcontact = data.data;
        }).catch(function(data) {
           //handle rejections here
        });
  }
```